# Fixed wrap with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page I have a div (fixed wrap) that I want to move after the scroll. 
I tried something with jQuery, but the height of the div is too high and goes over the footer.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxdpj.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z93cW.png)

Here's my code:

Sorry, edit2:

```js
var elementPosition = $('#fixed-wrapper').offset();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
    $('#fixed-wrapper').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0').css('margin', '20px 1%');
  } else {
    $('#fixed-wrapper').css('position', 'static');
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
 width: 101%;
 padding: 10px 0px 0px;
 margin: -10px -10px 10px -10px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 display: table;
 min-width: 700px;
}

#main-bets{
 display: table;
 float: left;
 width: 68%;
 margin-left: 7%;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 min-width: 900px;
 max-width: 900px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#fixed-wrapper {
     display: table;
     float: right;
     width: 22%;
     right: 5px;
     margin: 20px 1%;
     max-width: 300px;
}

#footer {
 width: 101%;
 padding: 10px 0px 0px;
 margin: 20px -10px -10px -10px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    ...
</div>

<div id="main-bets
    ...
</div>

<div id="fixed-wrapper">
 ....
</div>

<div id="footer">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding css on footer : `clear: both`. Could you provide html so that I could try?

Comment: I tried with `clear:both` but doesn't work

Comment: The html you added doesn't seem to be relevant with CSS and JavaScript, could you add relevant html for the layout you are trying to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [sticky float](https://github.com/yairEO/stickyfloat) jQuery plugin for that ([demo page](http://yaireo.github.io/stickyfloat/)), or use the relatively new CSS property: [position:sticky](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) (not [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) in older Egde/IE)

Answer (score 0):

Check now:

```
body {padding:0; margin: 0;}

#header {
    width: 101%;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: -10px -10px 10px -10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: table;
    min-width: 700px;
}

#main-bets{
    float: left;
    width: 68%;
  margin-left: 7%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 900px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#fixed-wrapper {
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 22%;
  right: 5px;
  margin: 20px 1%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

#footer {
    width: 101%;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 20px -10px -10px -10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    clear: both;
}
```

//---------------- HTML ---------- //

```
<div id="header">
    Header
</div>

<div id="main-bets">
    Bets
</div>

<div id="fixed-wrapper">
    Wrapper
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```